Error message not appearing in error email or in the error log
I am developing a plugin. I am getting an error when activating, but I can't find out what is causing the error, even which file is causing the error.
I don't receive an email for the fatal error, and nothing is added to the error_log file.
How can I find out what is causing the error?
Update:
Here's the code I'm using in the main plugin php file for error reporting:
//Turn on error reporting
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);
ini_set('log_errors', TRUE);
ini_set('error_log', '/my path/wp-content/plugins/pbcsc_cat_by_sub_cat/errors.log');
define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );
define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true );
error_reporting(E_ALL);
error_log('ajet.php starting');
//Set mysqli to report errors
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);

The error message I get when trying to activate the plugin is:
Plugin could not be activated because it triggered a fatal error.


Did you turn error reporting on? define( 'WP_DEBUG', true ); and define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true ); in your wp-config?

@rudtek: Yep, and even tried specifying the location for the error log.

That's a hard one.  What error are you actually seeing?

@rudtek: Added it to the question above, but it's Plugin could not be activated because it triggered a fatal error.

What host are you with?  Some hosts mess with the way debug works - I can't remember which one it was but I had it recently where all of the WP debug methods were ignored and over-ruled and I had to ask the hosting company to enable them.  All of my attempts at editing the wp-config.php resulted in no change to the errors being displayed.
